# Read xml file contains multi language characters corrupting characters of Japanese language

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Xml file with encoding mentioned as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

Contains some of the Japanese characters as mentioned below:

```
<Name>
    <![CDATA[熊本大学Slave_1002 大 [EL2002]]]>
</Name>
```

While reading the same file corrupts Japanese characters and it becomes name as

```
<Name><![CDATA[????Slave_1002 ? [EL2002]]]></Name>
```

Below is the code using to read the file.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new 
    StreamReader(filePath,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1")))
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
    }
```

Tried with encoding UTF-8 and unicode as well.

Comment: Small correction, It is Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") not Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1")) as mentioned above. Also, name becomes after reading file is: ????Slave_1002 ? [EL2002].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly check the specs and as far as I understand it CDATA section should have the same encoding as the rest of the document, but there are some [known issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Issues_with_encoding). Since you have already tried utf-8... is there any other encoding specified in doc preamble `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="like here" ?>`? It is strange that you can see those characters in text editor.

---

This encoding iso-8859-1 is Latin, there's no way it could handle Japaneese. So I created a test xml file like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Name>
  <![CDATA[熊本大学Slave_1002 大 [EL2002]]]>
</Name>
```

And VS told me to save it as UTF-8 and does not allow to select that iso as document encoding at all. I also write a test program

```cs
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\test.xml");
var val = ((XCData)xml.Root.FirstNode).Value;
Console.WriteLine(val);
File.WriteAllText(@"..\..\cdata.txt", val);
Console.ReadLine();
```

which gives me on console
[image]
but in text file..
[image]

To sum up:

1. I think the xml is not in declared encoding (at least partially)
2. `System.Xml.Linq` works fine so it's not a quirk or something
3. You might read that value correctly but you have troubles with viewing it.
4. I've changed declared document encoding as iso and use `new StreamReader(@"..\..\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8);` as `XDocument` source and the result was correct.

Comment: Hello @Bart, Thanks for your response. Only encoding="iso-8859-1" is specified at the very first line of the xml file. No any other encoding specified in the file. Still not sure what shall be done to read name from the file correctly without corrupting some of the characters.

Comment: Thanks @Bart, Yes, I see when I opened my xml in notepad++ and entered Japanese characters saved it and and opened again Japanese characters were converted to "????". Then Same file I open in notepad instead of notepad++ and enter Japanese characters, save it and run the code. It was read perfectly fine by the code as I entered. Here is code code using to read the same.  using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
      {
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(streamReader);
      }

Comment: So, to conclude as you mentionedproblem was because of encoding type only with which xml file was saved. Thanks for your time to response !!!